# OneToOne unidirectional mapping to one column in a composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I want to do a unidirectional OneToOne mapping to field which is inside an Embedded key.. I have been trying for 2 days. I am not able to proceed further. Any help is hugely appreciated. Below are my entities. Here i am trying to map VALUE_REF column in AuditMetaData to the VALUE_ID column of ValueMetaData. VALUE_ID is a part of embedded id.

AuditMetaData.class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class AuditMetaData{ 
   private Long id;
   private String tableName
   private String functionalTableName
   
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="VALUE_REF", referencedColumnName="VALUE_ID")
   private AuditValueMeta valueMeta
}
```

AuditValueMeta.class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class AuditValueMeta{ 
       
     @EmbeddedId
     private ValueMetaPK id;
   
     private String value
 }
```

---

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class ValueMetaPK{
  
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Integer id;
  
  @Column(name="VALUE_ID")
  private String valueId; 
}
```

Please ignore any syntatical errors.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated

Comment: @AjaySankaran I just noticed, how are you going to identify the `AuditValueMeta` only by `VALUE_REF` if for its identification you need to use a pair (ID, VALUE_ID). You can not create `foreign key (value_ref) references AuditValueMeta(value_id)` due to `ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Embeddable
public class ValueMetaPK{
  
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Integer id;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="VALUE_ID")
  private AuditValueMeta auditValueMeta; 
}
```

or alternatively:

```
@Entity
public static class AuditMetaData{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String tableName;
    private String functionalTableName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "auditMetaData")
    private AuditValueMeta valueMeta;
}

@Entity
@IdClass( ValueMetaPK.class )
public static class AuditValueMeta{

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "VALUE_ID")
    private AuditMetaData auditMetaData;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    private String value;
}

public static class ValueMetaPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;

    private AuditMetaData auditMetaData;
}
```

See [the hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated) for more details about the mapping.